# Is it possible to get gcc 4.2 or greater for synology ds213+(ppc)?

Tags: gcc, nas, powerpc, synology

I'm trying to compile node js for my synology ds213+, I've found this user on github https://github.com/andrewlow but I've to get gcc with version 4.2+. Unfortunately in ipkg repository there is only 3.4 version. After building from source I got error like "unknown arch".

Comment: I need an answer to this too. Did you figure it out?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at: https://github.com/Entware-ng/Entware-ng/wiki/Install-on-Synology-NAS

It seems that IPKG is abandoned, so that must be a good replacement.

Comment: For those reading this comment in/after 2020, note that Entware-ng merged with Entware-ng-3x to create a new project, Entware. It has its own instructions for installation: https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki/Install-on-Synology-NAS

The good news is that ARMv8 (AARCH64) is now fully supported! :-)